# I need help to read this code of a .lua file

Tags: lua

i want to read the next code, is library of commands in a .lua for a program called xenobot
the code is rly big
https://pastebin.pl/view/1539062b

Comment: You need Lua 5.1 decompiler to convert this bytecode to readable program.